# Scrolling all frames at once in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have `UIViewController` which contain `UIImageView` and `UITextView`. All views (and their frames) I added programmatically. `UIImageView` is small and on the top of `UIViewController` but `UITextView` is large and beyond the screen. Scrolling work only at TextView. How can I do scrolling for all `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add to your UIViewController's view an `UIScrollView` and the `UIImageView` and the `UITextView` inside the `UIScrollView` and set the UIScrollView's `contentSize` property  the appropriate values.